# how to bind generic list declared from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, treeview

I am creating a WPF application that allows the user to take a quiz then submit their answers and check the result in another page / xaml / window. My first page displays the list of questions in a ListView and a single button "Submit". The questions in my ListView are binded from a class that I created which is named "Question". It has 7 properties, namely: number, problem, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, and correct_answer. Only the property "correct_answer" is not displayed in the ListView. If user submits their answers and view the result, I want to be able to display the same list of questions with the correct answer in another xaml that is wrapped in a TreeView. My second page displays the score and result of the quiz. Users who prefer to check the correct answers can expand the TreeView.

QuizWindow.xaml

```
    <ListView Grid.Row="2" Name="list_question" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Content="{Binding number}"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding problem}"></Label>

                    <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding choice1}"></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding choice2}"></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding choice3}"></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding choice4}"></RadioButton>
                </Grid>   
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <Button Grid.Row="3" Content="Submit" Name="btn_submit" Click="btn_submit_Click"></Button>
```

Button click event to see result of the exam. QuizWindow.xaml.cs

```
    private void btn_submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ResultWindow resultWindow = new ResultWindow();
        resultWindow.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
```

ResultWindow.xaml

```
    <TreeView Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Review">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label Content="{Binding number}"></Label>
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding problem}"></Label>

                <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding choice1}"></RadioButton>
                <RadioButton Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding choice2}"></RadioButton>
                <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding choice3}"></RadioButton>
                <RadioButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding choice4}"></RadioButton>
            </Grid>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is the best solution, but you could pass the list<> into the constructor for result window

in QuizWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void btn_submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ResultWindow resultWindow = new ResultWindow(/*pass list in here*/);
    resultWindow.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

in ResultWindow.xaml.cs (psuedo code)

```
class ResultsWindow : Window
{

public ResultWindow(list<> answers)
{
    InitializeComponent();             

    //note: in resultwindow.xaml add name = "some_name" to treeview
    some_name.datacontext = answers_list;       

}
```

**EDIT**

in MainWindow.xaml

```
 <Window x:Class="passlist.MainWindow"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
 <Grid>        
     <StackPanel>           
         <Button Content="pass" Click="Button_Click"/>
         <ListBox Name="listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>            
     </StackPanel>
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

in MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<string> strings;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        strings = new List<string>();
        strings.Add("this");
        strings.Add("that");

        listbox1.DataContext = strings;


    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        passto pt = new passto(strings);
        if (!pt.ShowDialog() ?? false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("woohooo");
        }
    }
}
```

in passto.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="passlist.passto"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="passto" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="passlist" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

in passto.xaml.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for passto.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class passto : Window
{
    public passto(List<string> plist)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        passlist.DataContext = plist;

    }
}
```

this code is copied directly from the project I used to test the answer.

**END EDIT**

Comment: I appreciate your help. This sort of defeats the purpose of data binding.

Comment: how? this is data binding. are you looking for a pure XAML approach? because that is not part of your question. data binding may not be as smart as you think it is. ;)

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my previous comment. You're right.

Comment: I guess all that example code don't matter now. LOL

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. Now, I am currently trying to get the selected radio button from the list to check if user answered each item correctly. Hope I'll get it.